# Verifying in-App billing v3 with IABHelper

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm having trouble with this. I followed a tutorial online for setting it up and tested it using the test SKU. I literally just installed the SDK about 4 weeks ago so I'm not using super out-dated Google billing code. I'm using v3 of the in-app billing along with the IABHelper stuff.

When a user completes the purchase the IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener event is called. In that I check if IabResult is failure and if not I check to make sure the SKU and developer payload are correct. If they are I then attempt to consume the purchase.

Using queryInventoryAsync I attempt to get the item that was bought. The callback IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener is called and in there I again check if IabResult is failure.

If it's not failure I attempt to consume the item using consumeAsync which then has the callback IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener. In there I check again if IabResult is failure. If not I call my own server to fulfill the order.

Apparently there's more verification that I need to do because I just had an order come through about an hour ago that's not showing up in Google Wallet. I would think it would be there by now. I've found more than 3 different instructions/tutorial-ish pages on Google's own site for setting up billing version 3. On one of them it says to verify the signature, but it doesn't actually say how to do that. When I create an instance of IabHelper I'm passing in my base64 public key. IabHelper isn't verifying the signature? Do I have to use my own server to verify with Google? I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing so I can stop further theft.

Also, should I be receiving receipts by email when someone buys? Just out curiosity because I haven't been.

Edit: After looking through IABHelper it is verifying the signature. Is this problem to be expected and the only way to know if the order is real or not is to verify with my own server?

Comment: How would you verify with your own server? Have you found any code to do this? For some reason, an answer with code to this question is elusive.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to verify on your own server?